# How do I prove that this set is not R-approximable?

Tags: measure-theory

I have the following problem:

> Let $\Omega=[0,1]^2$ and $R$ the ring in $\Omega$ generated by $[a,b)\times[0,1]$ with $0\leq a<b\leq 1$. We define a measure on $R$ by $$\mu([a,b)\times[0,1])=b-a$$. In the first part I have shown that $$\langle R\rangle^\sigma =\{A\times[0,1]:A\in B([0,1])\}$$ where $B(...)$ is the borel sigma algebra. Now I need to show that the set $[0,1]\times \{\frac{1}{2}\}$ is not $R$ approximabel and we need to compute $\mu^*([0,1]\times \{\frac{1}{2}\})$.

In the lecture we saw that a set $X\subset \Omega$ is $R$ approximable with respect to the external measure $\mu^*$ if for each $\epsilon >0$ there is an $A\in R$ with $$\mu^*((X\setminus A)\cup(A\setminus X))<\epsilon$$ but in the exercise class one assistant said that $A$ needs to be in $$R^\uparrow=\{B\in P(\Omega): \exists A_k \,\,with\,\,\,A_k\subset A_{k+1}\,\,and\,\,B=\cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\}$$. This is the first confusion because I don't know what is correct now. The second one is that I don't see how to solve this exercise. Could someone help me please?

Comment: Depending on whether "$\subset$" means $\subseteq$ or $\subsetneq$, Either every $B \in P(\Omega)$ is in $R^\uparrow$ or else every infinite $B$ is in $R^\uparrow$. Perhaps there is more to the definition you didn't provide? In any case the lecture gave you the definition of $R$-approximable, while the assistant was giving you a clue on how to build such approximations $A$.

Comment: In this case, though, I would ignore the assistant, and instead pay attention to the fact that every $A \in R$ is $U \times [0,1]$ for some $U \subseteq [0,1]$, and therefore $U\times([0,1/2) \cup (1/2,1]) \subseteq A\setminus X$,